# Proper way to test scale and precision on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CreateWritingPatterns < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :writing_scores do |t|
      t.belongs_to :post, null: false
      t.float :adjectives_percentage, null: false, precision: 4, scale: 3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the `adjectives_percentage` has a precision of 4 and scale of 3. I would like to know if in my model `WritingPattern` I can add a validation for it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can. If the null false flag is set for it, I would start with a `validates :adjectives_percentage, presence: true` statement in your WritingScore model. I would enforce numerically as well. Beyond that, writing great test that simulates how your app could use this attribute will serve you well. Additionally, I would recommend reviewing the [Active Records Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) docs.

Comment: Rails built-in numericality validation does not really address floats or decimal. But its really easy to write your own validations. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom validation to validate `precision` and `scale`